# Moving website scraping from app to server, returning json

Tags: android, performance, html-parsing, web-scraping

I am working on a app that scrapes and parses html from 3rd party website and the performance isnt the greatest.

I was wondering what if I moved the scraping and parsing to server and just send json back to the app? Nothing gets cashed, server just acts as a middle man between app and website and parses html on every request.

So I was wondering, I know this is not optimal, but would this be faster than just app connecting and parsing html directly?

Has anyone experience doing this? I know it will differ from server to server and device to device, but just generally, whether its a good idea.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what are you doing. But I think its a good aproach to do that because it will decrease a lot the data traffic used by the phone/tablet.